# Why is user "lightdm" trying to log into my SBS 2003?

Tags: 12.04, networking, login, lightdm

I have 7 Ubuntu desktops connected to a **SBS 2003** using **Centrify**.
I have a rather weird scenario, whereby a user with the name **lightdm** is trying to log into our server, possibly automatically. I thought `lightdm` was the session manager, not a user?

*Does anybody know what could be causing this?*

There is no user: "**lightdm**" on the server and the problem only comes from one of the 7 internal desktops connected to the server (its IP address is in the local network).

Answer (score 0):

lightdm is a session manager and a user, lightdm runs as the lightdm user which has root privileges.

From /etc/passwd:

lightdm:x:104:112:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false

I'm curious what you mean by "trying to login" though, can you explain more?